# Copy characters from a String to a String

Tags: java

I'm working in a project and I'd like some help.

**So here's my test code :**

```
 package test;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {

        // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\karlk\\workspace\\Work\\src\\test\\tempx.txt";
        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;

        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  
            // Or we could just do this: 
            // ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**tempx.txt**

```
Karlken:Java:Male
```

This is my simple question

1) I want to write in a String called "name" the first word before the ':' (Karlken), the second word after ':' in another string (Java) , and in the end, again in another string I want to write "Male" how can I?

Comment: `line.split(":")`

Comment: Confused by your third string. You don't simply mean:

    String male = "male"; 

do you?

Comment: String string = "C:\\Users\\karlk\\workspace\\Work\\src\\test\\tempx.txt";
String[] parts = string.split(":");
String part1 = parts[0];
String part2 = parts[1];

Comment: @johncliffe what I want is 
String name = Karlken
String lang = Java
String sex = Male

from a txt file where is written "Karlken:Java:Male"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a scanner for this purpose:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\karlk\\workspace\\Work\\src\\test\\tempx.txt";

    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName))){
        scanner.useDelimiter(":");

        String name = scanner.next();
        String lang = scanner.next();
        String sex = scanner.next();            
    }catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
    }catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(
            "Error reading file '" 
            + fileName + "'");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
  String text = line;
  String[] parts = string.split(":");
  String part1 = parts[0];
  String part2 = parts[1];
  String part2 = parts[2];
}
```

Seems better for your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the text in the file is predefined (i.e. always 3 parts separated by a single `:`), then the following should be enough:

```
String text = readLineFromFile(filepath);
String[] parts = text.split(":");
String name = parts[0];
String lang = parts[1];
String gender = parts[2];
```

Comment: @yinon It looks like you copied code from john cliffe's answer.

Comment: @GriffeyDog It's the other way round. Check the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42097986/revisions) of john's post.

Comment: @Karlken That's pseodo-code, meaning that you will have to replace it with working code, i.e. `bufferedReader.readLine()`, as you already wrote when you asked the question.